# RabbitMQ java client stops consuming messages

Tags: java, heroku, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

My application consumes some messages from RabbitMQ and processes them.
I have about 10 queues and each queue has up to ten consumers (threads). 
I have a prefetch of 5. I'm running my setup in Heroku using the CloudAMQP plugin (RabbitMQ as a service).

I'm running with the default heartbeat and connection timeout settings (60 seconds).

My java application is a spring boot application using the spring-rabbit library.

Versions:

```
RabbitMQ 3.5.3 
Erlang 17.5.3
Java 1.8
Spring boot 1.3.2.RELEASE
Spring rabbit 1.5.3.RELEASE
```

The problem is that for the consumers of one particular queue stop consuming messages after some time. When I restart my java application everything works fine. The other queues are being consumed normally though. No errors on the application's side. On the log stream of rabbit's side I see some entries like

```
= REPORT==== 2016-08-02 15:53:32 UTC ===
closing AMQP connection <SOMETHING> (SOMETHING_ELSE -> SOMETHING_ELSE_ELSE):
{heartbeat_timeout,running}
```

I can't reproduce locally or in a testing environment in Heroku.

**Update**

The code below can be found in `AMQConnection.class`

```
int heartbeat = negotiatedMaxValue(this.requestedHeartbeat,
                                   connTune.getHeartbeat());


private static int negotiatedMaxValue(int clientValue, int serverValue) {
        return (clientValue == 0 || serverValue == 0) ?
            Math.max(clientValue, serverValue) :
            Math.min(clientValue, serverValue);
}
```

I can't increase the value of the heartbeat above 60 seconds (which is what I'm getting from the server).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this seems like a networking issue. This could be due to a few things:

- The CloudAMQP service is having some issues and is killing your connection (not likely since your other consumers are working OK).
- Your CloudAMQP plan doesn't allow for as many concurrent connections as you want. Have you checked to ensure you are on a sufficiently high enough plan to support all of your consumers? https://elements.heroku.com/addons/cloudamqp
- Your Heroku dyno with the consumer in question is restarting, which is dropping your connection. Heroku dynos periodically restart. If your dynos can't gracefully restart, you might want to investigate why.
- One of your Heroku dynos is having network issues (in which case it will likely be restarted on its own without your intervention).

One way to force all of your dynos to restart is to run `$ heroku ps:restart`. This will force Heroku to restart your dynos, which frequently means moving them to a new EC2 host. This may help if it is a one off issue.

Comment: Hello @rdegges. Thank you for your help. The plan is big enough to handle all the connections. Moreover (that's my bad, I wasn't clear enough) the consumers all work initially, but occasionally the consumers of this particular queue stop consuming. If I restart the app then everything works fine and the consumers start working again. I cannot reproduce it though. My app is running on one big machine (PL Web 1). I'm familiar with the nature of heroku infra (restarting etc.) and the application can handle this.

Comment: I was thinking that this could be due to overload which combined with the heartbeat configuration causes this. I'm waiting for this to happen again and see if this particular consumer connection is being dropped by rabbit, but the consumer remains unaware (this would explain the absence of any error logs). If this happens, then changing the heartbeat to a bigger value might fix it. But I don't know if this is possible. Check my update.

Comment: Ah, this makes it quite a bit more tricky to diagnose. Especially if it can't be easily reproduced :( But that consumer should restart the connection if it drops. Your heartbeat config looks fine to me.

Comment: What I'm thinking is that the connection is not dropped, but because of the small heartbeat window (let's assume that is small because of some unusual load) rabbit thinks that it's dropped and just discards and stops sending messages there. I believe that rabbit will NOT send some signal to its peer causing the client to be notified about this. Is that correct? That's why I'm thinking that if I increase the heartbeat interval, the client will have enough time to ping rabbit.

Comment: That is correct, although your heartbeat window seems fine. You said it is set to 60 seconds, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the default. It seems fine to me too, but that's just speculation. If this scenario is possible, then that's why I'm only seeing this behaviour very rarely and only in this particular consumer (which is doing some heavy lifting). I would like to try increasing the interval but I can't. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772773/increase-heartbeat-value-in-spring-rabbit.

Comment: Another potential workaround (if this happens rarely): use the Herkou platform API to restart your dyno if you notice the consumer is unresponsive after a certain timeout. You could run a one-off script like this via the Heroku scheduler.

Comment: Hi, I got the same issue but in a NodeJs environment. All of the sudden the consumer stops consuming without an error message or something.
Were you able to reproduce the problem or fix it?